# Is it possible to return a list of specific values from a query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have a list of documents in my "components" collection, each of which has the attribute "name". For example:

```
{
     "_id" : "ce83jfieojf8"
     "name": "George"
}
```

I would like to write a query that returns a complete list of all the name values from all documents in components.

Right now, I can use `db.components.find({'_id':0, 'name':1})`, and that will return something that looks like this:

```
{"name" : "George"}
{"name" : "John"}
{"name" : "Paul"}
```

And I can get the name of any individual one of those documents, using an index and the .name attribute.  If I put in

```
db.components.find({'_id':0, 'name':1})[0].name
```

I get:

```
George
```

However, what I want is a query that will return:

```
George 
John 
Paul
```

I've looked through the Mongo documentation, but when I search for 'returning multiple values' or 'returning lists', I only get lists of documents, not lists of values from those documents.

Is it possible to do this, or will I need to write a separate function to get each of those values individually?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let say you have the following documents in your collection:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7cfeeeb68594275546c76"), "name" : "George" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7cfeeeb68594275546c77"), "name" : "John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7cfeeeb68594275546c78"), "name" : "Paul" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7cfeeeb68594275546c79"), "name" : "Jack" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7cfeeeb68594275546c7a"), "name" : "Paul" }
```

- You can use [**`cursor.map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) to collect and return all names as array

```js
db.collection.find().map(function(u){ return u.name })
[ "George", "John", "Paul", "Jack", "Paul" ]
```

- If what you want is distinct `name` in your collection use  [**`collection.distinct`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```js
db.collection.distinct('name')
[ "George", "John", "Paul", "Jack" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return list of all `names` from all documents, you can use [$aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id:null,"name":{$push:"$name"}}},{$project:{_id:0,name:1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) like :

```
db.collectionName.distinct("name")
```